# Calling a public method from a different class

Tags: c#

I have a public class in class A that I would like to call from class B (see below) the public class return a true or false based on a stored procedure in the database. I have been trying to retrieve the value of the public string from class A in class B, but class B does not seem to find it.

Can someone point me in the right direction or show me a simple way to get my data from this public string?

```
public string IsProviderSameAsPCP
{
    get { return m_ProviderSameAsPCP; }
    set { m_ProviderSameAsPCP = value; }
}
```

Comment: So how are you trying to read this from your other class?

Comment: (It would also be worth learning about automatically implemented properties, as they cut down on boilerplate code.)

Comment: You do realize that when a member, like here the property `IsProviderSameAsPCP`, is non-`static` it belongs to ***instances*** of the class, that is to actual objects that "are" `A`? Therefore you can't say `A.IsProviderSameAsPCP`. Instead you have to give an object instance of type `A` before the dot `.`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 var myInstance = new YourClassName();
 var theString = myInstance.IsProviderSameAsPCP;
```

Comment: var myInstance = new Patient();
var theString = myInstance.IsProviderSameAsPCP;

Comment: but when i step through the  Patient class it does not even hit my sProviderSameAsPCP public method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to place the class in your namespace with the function/method inside of it. Then you can refer to the class by creating an instance and calling the embedded in it.

```
namespace YourNameSpace { 
 class AsPCP {
   public string IsProviderSameAsPCP {
    get { return m_ProviderSameAsPCP; }
    set { m_ProviderSameAsPCP = value; }
    }
  }
 }
```

Then from within your code:

```
   var newClassInstance = new AsPCP();
   var newString = newClassInstance.IsProviderSameAsPCP;
```